# ImportError for fftconvolve in PyDev

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pydev

Using the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

gives the following stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Erik/Documents/workspace- 
python/src/pywavelets/Problem1/Problem1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
  File "/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/signal/__init__.py", line 311, in <module>
    from . import sigtools, windows
  File "/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/signal/windows/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .windows import *
  File "/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/signal/windows/windows.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import fftpack, linalg, special
  File "/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/fftpack/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import _fftpack
ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not 
found: _main
  Referenced from: 
/Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/Erik/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

I've tried reinstalling numpy and scipy using pip, but didn't do anything.

Perhaps I need to specify some library in PYTHONPATH? I've read elsewhere that PyDev should automatically detect necessary imports, and numpy and tensorflow seem to work fine without any outside directories specified.

I do know that the error is specific to PyDev, since the code executes fine in the console.

Can anyone help me pinpoint the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in the console an not in PyDev, please check if your environment variables are the same in both cases.

i.e.:

```
for key, val in sorted(os.environ.items()):
    print('%s=%s' % (key, val))
```

Run both and save the output in different files and then compare to see what's different. The most likely culprits are `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`...

One thing to check is running Eclipse from the same console where you got things running (as it should inherit those variables).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Solution was to print the above code in both the console and PyDev. Comparing `PYTHONPATH` vs `PATH` and adding the `/Users/YOUR_USER_HERE/anaconda3/bin` folder in Eclipse under `Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter > Libraries` completely solved the issue.